# Prove the total surface area of the interior walls of the tank is $A = xy + 64(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this question that I need to use multivariable calculus to prove:

A rectangular tank, which is open at the top has a total volume of $32m^3$. The base has dimensions x and y

Show that the total surface area of the interior walls of the tank is $$A = xy + 64(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})$$

I'm not quite sure which direction I should take with this question, any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: how many directions have you got?

Comment: You know the base and the volume so you can solve for the height $h$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need "multivariable calculus" for this part (the part that may need it is likely to follow on after you prove this result).

You're not given the height, so denote it $z$.

The volume is $32$, so $z = \frac{32}{xy}$

The total surface area (omitting the open top) is $xy + 2(xz + yz)$. Simply substitute the expression for $z$ and simplify.